# what is meant by an algorithm to learn a Decision Tree from a set of training instances?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I'm pretty new to machine learning and I encountered a problem that states,

**Describe an algorithm to learn a Decision Tree from a set of training instances, mentioning one criterion for attribute selection.**

I'm confused Over the words **Learn** and **attribute selection** in this context, what do they mean? Isn't coming up with an algorithm that matches the input to the desired output the machine's duty? Sorry for the beginner question I only started learning two days ago, can someone help me out here? :)

Comment: Did you study decision trees? Because if not, then the question would obviously not make sense, you should study more before trying such problems.

Comment: I understand decision trees and the concepts behind it, I'm only new to the ML concepts mentioned here, what does learn mean here? does that mean generating a decision tree from the given training set?

Comment: I think you read a non-ML decision tree resource, because any classic ML book will cover decision trees/random forests and the algorithm to learn them.

Comment: oh darn, i didn't know there were ML specific decision trees, my bad

Comment: Decision trees are not ML specific but there are machine learning specific ways for constructing the trees and the question asks you to describe an algorithm that takes a dataset  on the input and outputs a decision tree.